# PHP Positioning entrys

Tags: php, position

I am pretty new to PHP so please be kind :).
I have been working on a system for a client to add products to a page, delete and edit thos products.
Now I am working on the positioning so I created a mysql entry "position".

My table has an auto-incremated id, title, description and position.

I have managed to set the positioning to the latest upload, for example if I have 3 entrys, the latest upload will get the position 4. Here is the upload script:

```
//UPLOAD SCRIPT

    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        $dirupload = "../images/";
        $dirupload = $dirupload . basename( $_FILES['image-upload']['name']);
        $titleupload = $_POST['title-upload'];
        $descriptionupload = $_POST['desc-upload'];
        $imageupload = ($_FILES['image-upload']['name']);
        $uploadedfileupload = $_FILES['image-upload']['tmp_name'];
        $uploadedfiletypeupload = $_FILES['image-upload']['type']; 



        $query="SELECT * FROM promotions ORDER BY position";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
        $add=$num+1;


        if (!($uploadedfiletypeupload =="image/pjpeg" OR $uploadedfiletypeupload =="image/jpeg" OR $uploadedfiletypeupload =="image/jpg")){
            echo "L'image doit être en .jpg ou .jpeg";
        }else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image-upload']['tmp_name'], $dirupload)){    
            $sql="INSERT INTO promotions (title, description, position) VALUES ('$titleupload','$descriptionupload','$add')";
            if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }



            $newnameupload = "../images/" . mysql_insert_id() . ".jpg";
            rename ("../images/$imageupload","$newnameupload");    
            $orig_imageupload = imagecreatefromjpeg("../image/$newnameupload");
            $sm_imageupload = imagecreatetruecolor(96,96);
            imagecopyresampled($sm_imageupload,$orig_imageupload,0,0,0,0,96,96,imagesx($orig_imageupload),imagesy($orig_imageupload));
            imagejpeg($sm_imageupload, $newnameupload, 100);

        }else{
            echo "Problem";
        }
    }
```

Now my problem is with the "up" and "down" entry to change the positions, I manage to add or substract 1 to the current position, the problem is I need to do the opposite to the next or prev one, here is the "up" script:

```
if (isset ($_POST['up'])){
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $position=$_POST['position'];
        $newPos=$position-1;

        mysql_query("UPDATE promotions SET position='$newPos' WHERE id='$id'");


    }
```

So I need to find the previous row and add 1, for example: If i have the second entry i want to put to first, click the "up" button, it gets moved up (that works) but i need to find the old first position and move it down once (that's the problem).

Hopefully I was clear enough, and thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) alert

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this should work placed before the update to your current product

```
mysql_query("UPDATE promotions SET position='$position' WHERE position='$newPos'");
```